# How to get high resolution images for Printers in .net?

Tags: .net, printing, device

If you go to "Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers" in Windows 7 (and i assume vista) you will see some nice pretty pictures of printers.

See image below

Is it possible to get access to these images through .net?

For example to display them on a windows form?

[example http://windows7-guide.com/images/articles/devices-and-printers.jpg](http://windows7-guide.com/images/articles/devices-and-printers.jpg)

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [maximumpc.com](http://www.maximumpc.com/files/u21826/header_DevPtr.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are available as .ICOs in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Device Metadata\dmrccache\`

See http://www.istartedsomething.com/20090605/admiring-windows-7s-high-resolution-device-icons/

Answer (score 2):

They'll be Microsoft copyrighted...

If you still really want to grab them there will be some DLL kicking around with them in. There's some in c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll although you'll need to check to see if these are the ones you want. You should then be able to extract the icons with an standard icon editor (e.g. IcoFx) straight from the DLL.

Comment: i dont thinks so. if u have an installed printer i think the manufacturer can pick the image. i have a several extra devices that have custom images. eg a Razer Copperhead and a Sandisk Cruzer which look exactly like the devices. unless MS has a database of device images?

Comment: here is a screen shot with custom images
http://www.maximumpc.com/files/u21826/header_DevPtr.png

Comment: Check out the printer drivers DLLs.

Comment: Don't extract the icon from the DLL and copy into your application.  Just locate the DLL at runtime and load the icon from the DLL's resources at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extract them from Vista's DLLs (also it's possible). take a look at [VitaIcons](http://www.vistaicons.com/), you can download completed vista icon set there. but if you need to use Vista's original icons, extract them by an icon editor program from kernal files and dlls of vista.

some icon editors:
http://www.rw-designer.com/vista-icon-editor
http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/downloads/vista_icon_editor_software/